# curl php ssl connection timeout

Tags: php, curl

I found this code in the internet and I modified it for my use, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I'm getting this error 
Curl error: SSL connection timeout
The login part is successful, but the search isn't working with me. can somebody help me with it please?

```
<?php
//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['username'] = 'user';
$post_data['password'] = 'log';
$post_data['cmd'] = 'log';

//create array of data to be posted
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
//create cURL connection
$curl_connection =
  curl_init('https://sie.com');
//set options
///curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3990);

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Connection: Keep-Alive',
    'Keep-Alive: 300'
));

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
//show information regarding the request

//print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
//echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
  //              curl_error($curl_connection);
//close the connection
//curl_close($curl_connection);


echo $result."\n";


$post_data1['cmd'] = 'Viewr';
$post_data1['search'] = 'test';



foreach ( $post_data1 as $key => $value1) {
    $post_items1[] = $key . '=' . $value1;
}
$post_string1 = implode ('&', $post_items1);
echo $post_string1."\n";
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
//perform our request
$result1 = curl_exec($curl_connection);
//show information regarding the request
//$result1 =1;
//close the connection
//curl_close($curl_connection);
if ($result1)
echo "ok \n\n";
else
echo "nok\n";
if(curl_errno($curl_connection))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl_connection)."\n";
}
echo($post_string1);
echo $result1."\n";


curl_close($curl_connection);


?>
```

Comment: Hi Craig, Not sure how to do that?

Comment: Next to the correct answer, below the rating

Comment: On your other questions, there is a checkmark next to all answers. Check the one which solved or assisted you in solving the issue. It matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this **(But don't leave this option set in production!)**:

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

If it works afterwards, it is because CURL is failing to negotiate the SSL Certificate.

Follow this tutorial for steps on how to obtain the CA cert: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Something else to look into is, **before** your curl_exec(), [`curl_copy_handle();`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-copy-handle.php) and then set additional parameters.

Additionally, or alternatively, you could re-initiate cURL with `curl_init($url);`.

Comment: it is set to false actually, I just checked it.

Comment: do you have Wireshark or TCPDUmp? Do you get a response back on 443? Or does it get hung on the TCP SYN?

Comment: So the login is working, which is the first curl_exec, but then the second curl_exec seems to be stuck

Comment: Try to re-initialize cURL the second time around as well. Or, close the first cURL and re-open cURL before the second block.

Comment: The second request seems to working ok, although for some reason I'm not getting what I want, I think I need investigate more, but again your solution is good

Answer (score -1):

Use the 2 options I listed to disable SSL verification temporarily, that *might* be it (if the certs aren't setup correctly).  Note the "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST" option.  Otherwise I'd just play with the options more.  Also you don't have to loop through those values, you can just use an associative array.

```
<?php
//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['username'] = 'user';
$post_data['password'] = 'log';
$post_data['cmd'] = 'log';

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = curl_init();
//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($curl_connection,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

//...

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);//it can accept associative arrays
```

//...

```
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

After trying the other answers, I was still getting the `SSL connection timeout` error.

I checked in my `php.ini` and decided to check if there was anything related to OpenSSL, and I did find that:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

I enabled it by uncommenting the line.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Now, with OpenSSL enabled (this is the parameter on Windows, it should be similar on Linux/Mac) and after restarting my Apache server, I can finally execute my cURL request without any error!